# SVN link folders

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have a visualSVN server and a eclipse connected to the svn repository! What i need is to have three folders:

- Android project folder
- iOS project folder
- www folder

how to make it so when i pull the Android project folder from the svn i have the www folder inside the project and when committing it commits the edited www folder to the www folder autside the android project folder so it could be done with both Android and iOS project because both will use the www folder? could someone help out?

Comment: Add the "www" folder as an external and include a reference to it in the other's [svn:externals property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *hd1* already mentioned: You can do this with [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html). Use the following commands to add the `www` folder to the directories `Android` and `iOS`:

```
svn propset svn:externals '../www www' Android
svn propset svn:externals '../www www' iOS
```

You can make changes to the directory `www` from all three folders, and all changed will be visible in all three folders. However, be careful when creating branches or tags. In most cases, you have to update the externals, too.